# Laravel: Eloquent Search not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This query is not filtering lower case product names, it works for capital case.

```
Products::select('productName')
            ->where('productName LIKE "%' . strtolower($searchWord) . '%"')
            ->where('statusID',1)
            ->orderBy('productID' ,'desc')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
Products::('productName')
            ->whereRaw('LOWER(`productName`) like ?', ['%'.strtolower($searchWord).'%'])
            ->where('statusID',1)
            ->orderBy('productID' ,'desc')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LOWER() operator to do that.